# Calculate |DE|, if AB || DE and: |AB|=21cm, |AC|=18cm, |AD|=6cm

Tags: geometry

I can't seem to understand the following task, what is it asking for and how would one solve it:

Calculate $|DE|$, if $AB || DE$ and: $|AB|=21cm, |AC|=18cm, |AD|=6cm$

From what I understand here what's going on there are two line segments that are parallel AB and DE. There are also three line segments going out from point A with certain lengths and of those AD is a distance between points A and D?

If so, how would one calculate this? If it isn't so, what is it and how would one calculate this?

Also, is |DE| for example here a distance between the two points or a line segment. I understand two things are the same - but I was wondering if there is a different notation for each? Thanks.

edit: could it be that ABC is here a triangle and D would lie on AC (6 from A) and in parallel to AB up to BC where E would lie on? That's my thinking anyways. I wouldn't be surprised if it's totally wrong line of thinking. If that's so, then |DE| would be 14cm?

Comment: A diagram, or other context, must be missing.

Comment: There is no other information. Hmm.

Comment: No diagram = no solution. Don't waste any more time wondering about this.

Comment: It must be it then. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be other interpretations, 
but most probably, 
the question is about a triangle $\triangle ABC$
and points $D\in AC$, $E\in BC$. 
Despite that the point $B$ 
can be located anywhere on a circle of radius $AB$,
the corresponding point $E$ would be located at a circle
with radius $DE$, which can be found from the proportion
$AB:AC=DE:DC$ since the triangles $\triangle ABC$
and $\triangle DEC$ are similar.

[image]